# Python библиотека, которая реализует управление устройствами ввода

Tags: python

Есть ли Питонавская библиотека, что реализует управление устройствами ввода (клавиатурой, мышкой), хочу узнать ее название. Не подскажете?

Comment: Чем управлять? Лампочкой поморгать надо или текст набрать?

Comment: Я же все достаточно подробно описал

Comment: У мышки нет моторчика чтоб ей управлять. А если говорите о курсоре, кликах и подобном, то хотяб операционную систему скажите. Но и тут Вы что хотите: получить движения или создать их?

Comment: Почти все библиотеки Python крос-платформенные, так что указание платформы не имеет смысла. А что вы хотели сказать своим вопросом я не понял

Comment: даже не все стандартные библиотеки кроссплатформенные, а уж взаимодействие с ос, то тут их единицы

Comment: Как раз наоборот, модуль ос поддерживает инструменты для реализации кроссплаформенности (конкретных примеров привести не смогу, сам модуль не очень знаю, но знаю, что есть, например, инструмент для указания пути к файлу независимо от ос, будь то Мак или Линукс который адаптирует путь в зависимости от ос), модуль tkinter - тоже самое, не говоря уже о том, что он сам позиционирует себя как не привязанный к какой то определенной платформе. Хоть я и привел всего 2 наиболее используемых модуля, не стоит забывать, что Python - не консервативный яп

Comment: ну это не взаимодействие с ос. Просто пара команд, а tkinter вообще рисует окна не используя операционную систему - потому они и смотрятся страшнненько.

Comment: А что тогда по вашему реализует взаимодействие с ос? Если вы не про уровень взаимодействия с ядром процессора

Comment: например inotify в линукс, запуск службы в виндовс. Но эта демагогия не относится к вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите управлять другими приложениями с помощью эмуляции клавиатуры и мыши, то https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ скорее всего подойдет

Comment: А можно с документацией на русском?

Comment: @Домино документации на русском найди врятли получится, но можно найди пару десятков статей как ей пользоваться.